# Is it acceptable for Domain Objects to create objects?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design

Please see the code:

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IDenomination> GetDenominations(decimal Cost, decimal PaymentReceived)
{
    decimal ChangeRequired = PaymentReceived - Cost;
    foreach (decimal CurrencyAmount in Currency.CurrencyDenominations())
    {
        if (ChangeRequired / CurrencyAmount >= 1)
        {
            int Quantity = (int)Math.Floor(ChangeRequired / CurrencyAmount);
            IDenomination  ChangeDenomination = ChangeDenominationsFactory.Create(CurrencyAmount, Quantity);
            yield return ChangeDenomination;
            ChangeRequired = ChangeRequired - (ChangeDenomination.Amount * ChangeDenomination.Quantity);
        }
    }
}
```

This method is part of a domain object.  The concern I have is that the Domain Object is responsible for creating objects via the factory.  Is this acceptable from a DDD point of view?

Yesterday I was reading a question that SLaks (https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) answered (or commented on) similar to this.  He suggests either using a factory or a Func delegate.  I did not save the links to my favourites.  I have spent nearly 1.5 hours searching for this question, however I cannot find it.  If anyone else can find it then please post the link.  I am wandering whether a Func delegate would be better (so that the class that contains the iterator above does not have to know about the factory.

Comment: It almost sounds like the question you really have is about _coupling_, rather than object creation.  If that's the case, you should open a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it acceptable for Domain Objects to create objects?

Yes, that's often where new representations come from.

See, for example, [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).  Or any of a myriad of examples in event sourced systems where the domain objects create the events that describe how they evolve over time.

Greg Young often uses a TradeBook as an example of an event sourced domain.  Orders arrive from the outside world, but the domain model is responsible for deciding which orders get paired together to make a Trade.  So the value object that represents that Trade is created within the domain model.

Whether that object is created via a direct call to its constructor, or by calling a method on some other object in the model, or invoking a method in a factory, or invoking a method on a domain service, is largely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

In DDD, i would expect this code in a service rather than a domain object.

It does not look like this code depends on any state of the domain object, so moving it to a domain service should be trivial.

Comment: This would make the domain model anemic, wouldn't it?

Comment: Anemia is about an entity not permiting to be in an invalid state and not about containing/being composed by all the Domain code

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU i don't recall state having anything to do with anemic domain models. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: @w0051977 that may be. i have no idea what the rest of your domain looks like. however, just putting stuff that shouldn't belong there in your domain so it isn't anemic is also an anti-pattern

Comment: @w0051977 furthermore, since this function does nothing with the state of the domain object, it has no business there.

Comment: @TimothyGroote of course it has. It is all about entities enforcing their own invariants by having command methods named from ubiquitous language that permit access to their internal state as opposed to having only setters.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU ah agreed! :) was having some trouble figuring out exactly what you meant